# What is “internal” and “external” network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, network-interface

> Lets say, I have to set up an **internal** and **external** network interface
>   in an Ubuntu VM. There will be another Ubuntu VM for some other
>   purpose. Both VMs are connected (they can ping each other) in the
>   Oracle VirtualBox.
>
> OR,
>
> Lets say, I have to set up an **internal** network interface in an Ubuntu
>   VM, and an **external** network interface in another Ubuntu VM. Both VMs
>   are connected (they can ping each other) in the Oracle VirtualBox.
>   Both VMs are connected (they can ping each other) in the Oracle
>   VirtualBox.

In the above scenario:

- What is "network interface"?
- What does it mean by "internal network
  interface" ?
- What does it mean by "external network interface"?

PS: I can set one or multiple network interfaces in Network Manager GUI inside Ubuntu VM

[image: Picture of network manager in Ubuntu OS]

Comment: anyone please? :(

Answer (score 1):

With VMs *(guest OSes)* and virtual switches:

- **External Interface:**

  - Virtual interface which is bridged with physical network hardware via a virtual bridge

    - Allows access to WAN

      .
- **Internal Interface:**

  - Virtual interface for local *host <-> guest* or *guest <-> guest* communication

    .
- **Private Interface:**

  - Virtual interface for local *guest <-> guest* communication only

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the network interface is network interface card(NIC). However, the network interface doesn't have to have a physical form. It can be implemented in software.

The internal network interface is one of computer hardware that connects the computer to network.

The external interface has multiple form, it can be an Ethernet card, a modem, a DSL modem, or a dial-up analog modem.

These concepts can be easily searched by google, I have added my understanding about this. I hope this can help you.